# Cosmos DB flat VS nested design

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is this Cosmos DB (SQL API) query:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Name = 'John'
```

Faster or cheaper than

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Personal.Name = 'John'
```

I'm trying to understand the consequences of designing my data flat VS nested (not normalized vs de-normalized).

Thanks

Comment: Easiest way to see the impact is just try it out and see the change in RU. Short answer: yes it will use slightly less RU which make sense as the document is slightly smaller. It however is such a minimal increase that it should not weight in your decision going for one or the other. (edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two versions of query you mention are probably very close in terms of cost, but the more important impact of model complexity in my experience is the cost of writes. Cosmos creates an index by default for every [possible path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-overview#querying-with-indexes) from the item root. That means the more complex your model, the more paths will be indexed, which directly increases the cost of a write operation. As the [indexing docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy) note:

> By optimizing the number of paths that are indexed, you can
> substantially reduce the latency and RU charge of write operations.

So if you embed a `Personal` item within your root item with multiple properties, you make your item more expensive to write.

There are also quite a few questions on StackOverflow from people asking how to write queries for their complicated object models, who never like the comment "why not a more straightforward model?" If you have the chance, avoid that fate. :)

In general, keeping items as simple and small as possible seems like the rule of thumb to follow. As always, test and see. The RU cost of queries are deterministic so you can directly know the impact of a change just by tweaking variables and running a quick test.